# Randomly generate country name from an API

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, random, react-hooks

I'm using https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all to fetch all the names of countries.

I'm trying to generate a random country name on a click. I've mapped through the array of object to get the names of countries, but `onClick` doesn't work.

```
const WorldCard = () => {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState([])
    const [name, setCount] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                setCountry(result)
                console.log(result)
            })
    }, [])

    const countryName = country => {
        return country.map(d => d.name)
    }

    return (
        <Card>
            <Card.Body>{name}</Card.Body>
            <Button
                onClick={() =>
                    setCount(countryName[Math.floor(Math.random() * countryName.length)])
                }
            >
                Click me
            </Button>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`countryName` is a function but you were using it like an array. So you need to map your response at the time of setting data and you can directly use then. Try below code

```
const WorldCard = () => {
    const [country, setCountry] = useState([])
    const [name, setCount] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                setCountry(countryName(result))
                console.log(result)
            })
    }, [])

    const countryName = country => {
        return country.map(d => d.name)
    }

    return (
        <Card>
            <Card.Body>{name}</Card.Body>
            <Button
                onClick={() =>
                    setCount(country[Math.floor(Math.random() * country.length)])
                }
            >
                Click me
            </Button>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

Comment: thank you!! what if i would like to access the other objects within the array? am i able to map more than 1 object within `countryName` function? @Neel

Comment: Not required. You can add in the same map function like this `return country.map(d => {d.name, d.anotherObject})`

Comment: thank you! i did this: 
`country.map(d => ({name: d.name, population: d.population}))`
@Neel

Answer (score 1):

As all the data is coming in the form of Objects inside array. What you can do is instead of trying to generate random country name, generate random number and pass it. So you will get random countries on button click.
A little fix here.

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
const [randomCountry, setRandomCountry] = useState(0)

<Button onClick={() => setRandomCountry(Math.floor(Math.random() * countries.length))}> // this will just set the number for random country. pass randomCountry to useEffect as dependency array or you can use it some way in countries.map()
     Click me
</Button>
```